# Invalid Object in Oracle PL/SQL in a recently created object when creating a package

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'd like to know why the compiler returns `PLS-00905: object FELIPE.T_COPY_INCONSISTENCIES_TAB is invalid` when I recently created my object.

It doesn't seems to have any problems in the code regarding the the type type object and type creation.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Felipe.T_Copy_Inconsistencies_Row AS OBJECT(
        book_id INT NOT NULL,
        branch_id INT NOT NULL,
        copies_diff INT NOT NULL
    );
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Felipe.T_Copy_Inconsistencies_Tab IS TABLE OF Felipe.T_Copy_Inconsistencies_Row;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Felipe.Copy_Inconsistencies_Pack 
        IS 
            FUNCTION Get_Copies_Inconsistencies RETURN Felipe.T_Copy_Inconsistencies_Tab PIPELINED;
        END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, I just needed to remove the `NOT NULL` in the object creation because the database required a default value for it.